# Convert sql statement to linq - using datepart and grouping

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

The SQL below returns a count of records updated by week.
I have recreated in linq the part that returns the count by week(below) but I can't get the **startofweek** and **endofweek** columns.  Help

**SQL**

```
select 
DATEPART(wk, audit_date) week, 
count(audit_date) updatedRec, 

dateadd (week, DATEPART(wk, audit_date),  dateadd (year, DATEPART(year, audit_date)-1900, 0)) - 4 -  datepart(dw, dateadd (week, DATEPART(wk, audit_date),  dateadd (year, DATEPART(year, audit_date)-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1 startofweek,


dateadd (week, DATEPART(wk, audit_date), dateadd (year, DATEPART(year, audit_date)-1900, 0)) - 4 - datepart(dw, dateadd (week, DATEPART(wk, audit_date), dateadd (year, DATEPART(year, audit_date)-1900, 0)) - 4) + 7 endofweek

from itims.Listings_Audit
where audit_type = 'U' and datepart(year,audit_date) = '2014'
Group by DATEPART(wk, audit_date),  DATEPART(year, audit_date)
order by startofweek, week
```

**Linq**

```
    var data = (from p in _db.Listings_Audit
            where p.audit_type == "U"
            where p.audit_date.Value.Year == 2014
            group p by new
            {
                Column1 = (int?) SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", p.audit_date),
                Column2 = (int?) SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", p.audit_date)
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                week = g.Key.Column1,
                updatedRecCnt = g.Count(p => p.audit_date != null),


            }).OrderBy(g=>g.week).ToList();
```

Comment: As a side note, these queries will be as slow as possible.  Your *where* and *group by* statements are not [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: When you use `LINQ` to query `DB` you must tell us about specific technology you are using such as `LINQ2SQL` or `LINQ2Entities`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Since the OP is using `SqlFunctions` this requires Linq2Entities

Comment: @arserbin3, really? I see so much developers who try to use `SqlFunctions` with `LINQ2SQL` or such things.

Answer (score 1):

This Linq2Entities query will give you the **startofweek** and **endofweek**. However, for large lists, you may see performance issues on these sort of calculations.

This makes use of [EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime) to calculate the dates based on year and week.

### Linq Query:

```
var data = (
    from p in _db.Listings_Audit
    group p by
        new
        {
            Column1 = (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", p.audit_date),
            Column2 = (int)SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", p.audit_date)
        }
    into g
    select
        new
        {
            week = g.Key.Column1,
            year = g.Key.Column2,
            startOfWeek =
                EntityFunctions.AddDays(
                    EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(g.Key.Column2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                    (7 * (g.Key.Column1 - 1))),
            endOfWeek =
                EntityFunctions.AddDays(
                    EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(g.Key.Column2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                    (7 * (g.Key.Column1))),
            updatedRecCnt = g.Count(p => p.CreatedDate != null),
        }).OrderBy(g => g.startOfWeek).ToList();
```

- Note: If your rows contain `null` dates you will need to make use of `GetValueOrDefault()`. However, based on your example limiting it to `"2014"`, this shouldn't be an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

A friend gave me the answer I needed.  The results matched my sql output.

```
var data = (from p in _db.Listings_Audit
                    where p.audit_type == "U"
                    where p.audit_date.Value.Year == 2014
                    group p by new
                    {
                        Column1 = (int?)SqlFunctions.DatePart("wk", p.audit_date),
                        Column2 = (int?)SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", p.audit_date)
                    }
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                            week = g.Key.Column1,
                            updatedRecCnt = g.Count(p => p.audit_date != null),
                            year = g.Key.Column2

                        }).OrderBy(g => g.week).ToList().Select(y => new
            {
                week = y.week,
                y.updatedRecCnt,
                startofweek = new DateTime(y.year.Value, 1, 1).AddDays(-(int)new DateTime(y.year.Value, 1, 1).DayOfWeek).AddDays(y.week.Value * 7 - 7),
                endofweek = new DateTime(y.year.Value, 1, 1).AddDays(y.week.Value * 7 - 1).AddDays(-(int)new DateTime(y.year.Value, 1, 1).DayOfWeek)
            });
```